# Generate N user controls (partial views)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, html.renderpartial

I am trying to migrate a project from web forms to mvc. I need page(view) where i can render N partial views and submit the data. Model should look something like this:

```
    public class ContactInfo
    {
        Contact customer{get;set;}
        List<Contact> guests {get;set;}
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this. I know about @HTML.RenderPartial but i have problem submiting that data. Another problem that i have is that some of the fields are required depending on what contact type they belong. At first it will be great help if i can just submit that data. Later will find solution for required field, maybe some custom validators or something. As i said or not i am new to this so something of this may sound stupid.